# Laravel Compilation "Error: Cannot Find PATH/node_modules/laravel-mix/.."

Tags: node.js, laravel, webpack, npm-install, laravel-mix

When I run commands like:

```
npm run dev 
npm run watch
```

to compile my project. I receive an error that says the laravel-mix directory does not exist.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'PATH/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'
```

I have deleted the node_modules directory and used `npm install` to attempt to get it to install properly and it still is not there. "Laravel-mix" is in the package.json file as a dependency, so to my knowledge running `npm install` or `npm install laravel-mix` should do the trick, but it isn't working. Any information about this would be greatly appreciated.

```
npm -v 6.14.1
node -v 12.16.2
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you already run the following?

```
npm install laravel-mix
npm install cross-env
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with node v14.17.5, update your node to last version, everything will work after update node to v18.6.0.